# DB query For H2 Database (update column with incremental values based on some other column)

Tags: sql, h2

I have existing table transactions(CustomerName,transactionAmount)

```
(Ravi,300)
(Ravi,500)
(Muki,300)
(muki,100)
(Ravi,3400)
(Sandeep,900)
```

Now I added a new column to this table(transactionId)
Its values should be incremental but based on names...like enteries of name Ravi should have transaction id 1, with muki id 2 and so on...

```
**CustomerName,transactionAmount,transactionId**
(Ravi,300,1)
(Ravi,500,1)
(Muki,300,2)
(muki,100,2)
(Ravi,3400,1)
(Sandeep,900,3)
```

I need a update query for updating these transaction ids for H2 database.

Please be informed H2 does not support syntax for Row_Number()

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Have you tried anything so far or do you have ideas about some things you want to try? It sounds like you simply need to track customer transaction IDs in a table somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want using a correlated subquery.  You are not clear if the order of the numbers matters, but this may do what you want

```
select t.*,
       (select count(distinct customername) from transactions t2 where t2.customername <= t.customername)
from transactions t;
```

I think you can put this in an `update`:

```
update transactions t
    set transactionId = (select count(distinct customername)
                         from transactions t2
                         where t2.customername <= t.customername);
```